# Firebase Authentication: Create self defined expiry token with Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase 3.4.1 for web. Token expiry by default is too long which is fine also to maintain user on app. But i want to manage expiry manually so that by default token should be session only and if user select 'Remember Me' then it should persist for long.

Comment: Is your preference to use session only persistence? Basically the session would be cleared when the window is closed? or do you want to set a fixed expiry date to a session?

Comment: Hi Thanks for your Reply,
My preference if for session first than expiry but if you have an solution for expiry also then let me know that also.

Comment: I added a possible solution below that you may be able to use. Session only persistence has already been requested: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/firebase-talk/session$20only%7Csort:relevance/firebase-talk/uYMlQny1Jb4/Xnk1NJB3HQAJ

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase ID token has an auth_time field (in UTC seconds) for the time the user signed in. You can check that and if it exceeds your desired session length, force a sign out. If you are using realtime database rules, you can restrict access to users with auth_time exceeding a certain delta to certain resources.